# Formula in common: How to search for same/similar equations in other knowledge domains?

Tags: soft-question, research-practice

In a recent presentation by Sedgewick, he recounts in 1977 Flajolet noticed that they had a formula in common, both in different domains (see slide 4 in http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/talks/AofA2AC.pdf )

I saw the same thing in an article on tantalizing links between matrix eigenvalues distributions, nuclear physics and Riemann's zeta zeros http://web.williams.edu/go/math/sjmiller/public_html/RH/Hayes_spectrum_riemannium.pdf

My question is: Say I have derived a formula/equation - how would I go about searching for an occurrence of the formula in other domains? Can I make Wolfram Alpha do that?

Thanks for any pointers

Daniel Bilar

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for [academia.se].

Comment: Maybe, but it's not a perfect fit in either place. So why not leave it here. At least the context is closely related to tcs.